# Django form start date end date validation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to validate that the end date is greater than the start date.  This is a form editing an entry submitted in a previous form.  The startdate field has already been populated.

This function was written based on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/)

When I submit the form there is no error thrown.

Is this function called simply by submitting the form?  What am I missing?

```
class EditForm(ModelForm):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Cast
  
        fields = [
            'enddate',
        ]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('startdate')
        end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('enddate') 
        if end_date < start_date:
            raise ValidationError("End date must be greater than start date")
```

View:

```
def castend(request, id):
    context ={}
    obj = get_object_or_404(Cast, id = id)
    form = EditForm(request.POST or None, instance = obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        cast=Cast.objects.last()
        cast.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/cast/%i/castenddetail" % cast.pk)
 
    context["form"] = form
```

Template:

```html
    <!--template/castenddetail.html-->
    {% extends "wwdb/base.html" %}
    
    {% block content %}
    <header>
        <h1>Cast ended successfully</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="cast-entry">
        <p>Start date: {{cast.startdate}}</p>
        <p>End date: {{cast.enddate}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Model:

```
class Cast(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)  
    startdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartDate', null=True, verbose_name='Start date and time')  
    enddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='EndDate', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='End date and time')  

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Cast'
        verbose_name_plural = "Cast"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('castdetail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.startdate)
```

I was expecting to see the error "End date must be greater than start date"

In reality, the form submits no problem with an end date that is less than the start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a blend of the responses, this is the answer I chose:

Form:

```
class EditForm(ModelForm):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Cast
  
        fields = [
            'startdate',
            'enddate',
        ]
        
    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super().is_valid()

        if hasattr(self, 'cleaned_data') and valid:

            start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('startdate')
            end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('enddate')
            if not end_date:
                self.add_error('enddate', 'Please enter end date')
                valid = False
            elif end_date < start_date:
                self.add_error('enddate', 'End date must be greater than start date')
                valid = False
        return valid
```

I chose to validate the enddate field in the form rather than the model.  Upon initially submitting the cast, the startdate field is entered and the enddate is not displayed in the form/is null in the database. enddate is added upon submission of the edit form.  The enddate field must allow null values. The startdate field is validated in the model.

view:

```
def castend(request, id):
    context ={}
    obj = get_object_or_404(Cast, id = id)
    form = EditForm(request.POST or None, instance = obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cast=Cast.objects.last()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            cast.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/wwdb/cast/%i/castenddetail" % cast.pk)
    context["form"] = form
    return render(request, "wwdb/castend.html", context)
```

While is_valid=False, redirect back to the edit cast view.  While is_valid=True, redirect to the detailed view of the submitted cast.

Model:

```
class Cast(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    startdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartDate', null=False, verbose_name='Start date and time') 
    enddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='EndDate', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='End date and time')  

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Cast'
        verbose_name_plural = "Cast"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('castdetail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Template:

```
<!--templates/castend.html-->
{% extends "wwdb/base.html" %}
{{ form.media }}

{% block content %}
<h1>End Cast</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using the `is_valid` function instead of `cleaned_date`

```py
class EditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cast

        fields = [
            'enddate',
        ]

    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super().is_valid()

        # Double Check
        # 1: if no data was posted, cleaned_data won't exist - empty form submit
        # 2: if valid: all required fields (start + end) are valid // is not None
        if hasattr(self, 'cleaned_data') and valid:

            start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('startdate')
            end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('enddate')
            if end_date < start_date:
                self.add_error('enddate', 'End date must be greater than start date')
                valid = False

        return valid
```

~I also added a check to see if `enddate` exists in the first place.~
~No point of showing the **greater than** error if the **is required** error will be shown (from the `.super()`)~

---

#### Edit:

Actually, I think you just need to change your `raise ValidationError("End date must be greater than start date")` to `self.add_error('enddate', 'End date must be greater than start date')`
I've always done the `is_valid` way, but the docs make it seem like you can do it in `clean`

Comment: What is this `if end_date and end_date < start_date:` why only `end_date` it should be like this `if end_date and start_date and end_date < start_date:`

Comment: @SunderamDubey you're correct, I just didn't want the line to be too long and I assumed `datetime < None` would be false.

Comment: @BonnyClarke I've updated my code. if `cleaned_data` isn't defined that usually means you submitted the form with no data- which is weird -but I've ran across it a few times.. i also added the `if valid` so it won't run your custom stuff if it fails the default stuff

Comment: @BonnyClarke check my below answer one time.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I hope it works yo, cause I'm getting confused lol

Comment: Ok, I think I am moving in the right direction here.  Now I get the error: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'.  I am doing some research on the proper way to compare dates.  If anyone has a quick answer, I am listening!

Comment: @BonnyClarke I already told you in the comment below my answer that  we can't tell anything without seeing your relevant code such as models, views and template associated. And you haven't replied there yet?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I was replying as you were writing this.  It took me a minute.

Comment: @BonnyClarke Just make plop an `if startdate and enddate` before you do the compare. that's the easy fix. but you should look into making those fields required in the form- that way django will automatically reject it and it won't hit your custom validation

Comment: @Nealium See my comment below with the solution I came up with.  Thanks for the help!  I handle the startdate validation in the model, but because the form is initially submitted with the enddate blank, the enddate needs to be handled in the form.  I'm happy with the end result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
class EditForm(ModelForm):
      
    class Meta:
        model = Cast
        fields = [
            'startdate',
            'enddate'
        ]
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        start_date = cleaned_data.get('startdate')
        end_date = cleaned_data.get('enddate') 
        if end_date and start_date and end_date < start_date:
            raise ValidationError("End date must be greater than start date")
```

Use the following view:

```py
def castend(request, id):
    context ={}
    obj = get_object_or_404(Cast, id = id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            cast=Cast.objects.last()
            cast.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/cast/%i/castenddetail" % cast.pk)
    else:
        form = EditForm(instance=obj)
    context["form"] = form
    context["cast"] = obj
    return render(request, 'template/castend.html', context)
```

You can use the `form.errors` attribute to display the validation errors in the template, like this:

```html
<!--template/castend.html-->
{% extends "wwdb/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<header>
    <h1>End cast</h1>
</header>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <ul>
        {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Still not working.  Maybe I am missing something more basic.  Does this function need to be called, or does submitting the form call the function?  I am expecting the form to not submit and instead me see this error.  As it stands when I submit the form I redirect to a detailed view of the cast.  No error arises.

Comment: @BonnyClarke Can you share your relevant view and the template by editing the question?

Comment: @ sunderamdubey Just edited the original question to provide this.

Comment: Still not raising an error.  I was wondering if I needed to include the startdate field in this form and just prepopulate it, but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: @Bonny Can you also share `Cast` model? Again see the edited answer.

Comment: I added the model.  I have a noteworthy discovery.  With your most up to date edits I redirect to the detail page, but the enddate field has a 'none' value, rather than the unacceptable date.

Comment: @BonnyClarke Again try the edited answer.

Comment: upon submitting the form I redirect to castenddetail, even if there was an error thrown.  Does there need to be an else statement beneath "if form.is_valid()" that redirects back to the edit form? Playing around with this but not getting useful results.

Comment: @BonnyClarke Yes it should be for what is to be done if the form is not valid, for example redirecting to some error page. Have you tried the answer is it working?

Comment: No, it still redirects to the detail view without displaying an error.  it does not accept the enddate value, but I would like the used to be redirected back to the form with an error displayed so they can fix it.  I could write a view that is an editcast page with bright red wording screaming error, but that still allows the user to submit the form.  Probably not the most elegant way to handle the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252303/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-bonny-clarke).